# Advice for storing votes with Prisma&Mongo

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, prisma

I've been using MongoDB for a few years now, and I'm starting to use Prisma's client, which seems to be providing excellent type safety. I'm not familiar at all with relational data storage, though...

This is how my database is looking:

- Users are each associated with a single group
- Each one of them can be a candidate in the group, and all vote for one of the group candidates during an election once they've been selected

What best practices would you advise me to follow here to **store the votes**? (I'm not talking about the privacy perspective specific to voting, this is a whole other topic, but only the performance & data storage stance)

---

Typically with MongoDB, I would create an **embedded object** in the Group document, with the User **IDs of candidates as the keys**, and an **array of the User IDs of the voters for each candidate as the values**.

But strong types & the relational database-inspired approach of Prisma seem to prevent me from doing anything like that, most likely for the better.

Answer (score 0):

In a relational database, you would typically create a separate table to store the votes. Each row in the table would represent a single vote and would contain the following columns:

```
group_id: the ID of the group in which the vote took place

candidate_id: the ID of the candidate who received the vote

voter_id: the ID of the user who cast the vote
```

You can also add a timestamp column to store the date and time when the vote was cast.

To get the votes for a particular group, you would perform a query like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM votes WHERE group_id = :groupId;
```

You can then use the results of this query to build the necessary data structures in your application.

Using a separate table to store votes has the advantage of keeping the data normalized, which can make it easier to work with and more performant. It also allows you to use foreign key constraints to ensure that each vote references a valid group and candidate.